# Compiling Programs with arm-none-eabi

Tags: arm

first timer here, just wanna ask what happens if you compile something designed for a specific board like say raspberry pi but instead of using those compiler targets you use arm-none-eabi? Will it break the software or what?

Comment: Define "something". There's quite a difference between e.g. some bare-metal code and a Linux userspace app.

Comment: Lets say I want to compile the kernel for raspbian but instead of for raspberry pi, I compile for another arm platform like the beagle board would using arm-none-eabi work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your intent is to build a user space program that will execute on a Raspberry Pi running Linux, then `arm-none-eabi` is not the right toolchain to use because it has no libc (and it lacks other libs as well). You will not be able to build your application.

Comment: Yea sorry for being too ambiguous I'm trying to compile something like the kernel but I'm asking if it would work if I used arm-none-eabi instead of the raspberry pi architecture targets.

Comment: @bananafish you should be able to build the bootloader or the kernel with a bare metal toolchain.

Comment: Thank you very much. Would the kernel run on any arm chipset though?

Comment: @bananafish no, ARM is not like x86 where the same kernel can run nearly everywhere. Even if you can build multi-platform kernels for ARM, a multi-platform ARMv7 image will not run on an ARMv5 device.

Comment: Oh yea ik. I know that part. I was just making sure it could run on all processors of the same version of the architecture. So compile arm-none-eabi for arm 7 means any arm7.